# Firefox extensions: How to run function on every video change on YouTube

Tags: javascript, youtube, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have an extension that injects `js` code into YouTube pages. I've used the following declaration in `manifest.json`:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "*://*.youtube.com/*"
        ],
        "js": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    }
]
```

I would like to define the function that prints the name of the video, number of likes and dislikes to console when I move to another video.

I've written this in `background.js`:

```
window.onhashchange = function () {
    console.log(
        document.querySelector("h1.title > yt-formatted-string:nth-child(1)").innerHTML, "\n",
        document.querySelector("ytd-toggle-button-renderer.ytd-menu-renderer:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1) > yt-formatted-string:nth-child(2)").getAttribute("aria-label"), "\n",
        document.querySelector("ytd-toggle-button-renderer.style-scope:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1) > yt-formatted-string:nth-child(2)").getAttribute("aria-label"), "\n",
    )
}
```

But it runs only once. If I select new video from "Recommended" it does not work. I also tried `.onload`, `.onunload`, etc.

UPD: Now the only way I found is to use `.setInterval`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several possible solutions using the [WebExtensions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API), all require a background script that will send messages to your content script. Modify your `manifest.json` to include:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
```

I've named the [background script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/background) `background.js` here, that would collide with what you currently have - you might want to consider to rename your [content script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts) to something like `contentscript.js`, so you don't get the two confused.

In the `contentscript.js` you have the message listener

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(message => {
    if (message.videoChanged) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

---

#### Using [`tabs.onUpdated`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onUpdated)

Needed permission in the `manifest.json`

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs"
]
```

In the `background.js`

```
browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    if (!changeInfo.url) {
        // url didn't change
        return;
    }

    const url = new URL(changeInfo.url);
    if (!url.href.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/watch?') ||
        !url.searchParams.get('v')) {
        // not a youtube video
        return;
    }

    browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {videoChanged: true});
});
```

This method will message the content script on first visits, while on-site navigation or auto play.

---

#### Using [`webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webNavigation/onHistoryStateUpdated)

Needed permission in the `manifest.json`

```
"permissions": [
    "webNavigation"
]
```

In the `background.js`

```
browser.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(history => {
    const url = new URL(history.url);
    if (!url.searchParams.get('v')) {
        // not a video
        return;
    }

    browser.tabs.sendMessage(history.tabId, {videoChanged: true});
},
    {url: [{urlMatches: '^https://www.youtube.com/watch\?'}]}
);
```

This method messages the content script while on-site navigation or auto play.

---

#### Using [`webRequest.onBeforeRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest) or [`webRequest.onCompleted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onCompleted)

YouTube makes a xmlhttrequest when the video changes. You can see the requests by opening the Developer Tools (Ctrl+Shift+I), selecting the Network tab, select `XHR`, filter by `watch?` and then let YT switch to the next video. You'll see that two requests occur for the next video, one with a `prefetch` parameter in the URL shortly before the video changes, and one when the video actually changes without the `prefetch` parameter.

Needed permissions in the `manifest.json`

```
"permissions": [
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?*",
    "webRequest"
]
```

In the `background.js`

```
browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(request => {
    const url = new URL(request.url);
    if (!url.searchParams.get('v') || url.searchParams.get('prefetch')) {
        // not a video or it's prefetch
        return;
    }

    browser.tabs.sendMessage(request.tabId, {videoChanged: true});
},
    {urls: ['https://www.youtube.com/watch?*'], types: ['xmlhttprequest']}
);
```

`onBeforeRequest` might be a bit too fast and send the message to the content script before the new video actually finished loading. In this case you could just replace it with `onCompleted`.

This method messages the content script while on-site navigation or auto play.

Answer (score 0):

Well the idea is to find a way to periodically check for URL change so the trick I use is to take advantage of the user's need to click on things like the play/pause button and of course on other videos to watch.

So inside your page **onload** event... (W being your iframe ID)

```
 if(W.contentWindow.document.URL.indexOf('www.youtube.com/watch?v=')>-1){ // You may want to add some more permissable URL types here

   W.contentWindow.document.body.addEventListener('click',function(e){ CheckForURLChange(W.contentWindow.document.title,W.contentWindow.document.location); },false);

 }
```

And further down with the rest of your functions...

```
function CheckForURLChange(Title,URL){

  // Your logic to test for URL change and take any required steps

 if(StoredURL!==URL){}

 }
```

It's not the best solution but it does work.

Comment: It's nice trick but it won't work if you use autoplay feature and videos change automatically